# How to minimize perpendicular strain on cam-follower system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses

I have a cam+follower system as shown in the picture:
[image]
As the arched cam moves in the horizontal direction, the (fixed) follower gets pushed in the vertical direction. But as the cam approaches the extreme points of its motion, the side strain on the follower is high due to the high curvature of the cam side: the force at that point is far from parallel to the follower shaft and there is a risk of the mechanism not working properly.
Is there a different mechanical design for the follower that could minimize the side strain?

Comment: To reduce strain without changing the cam geometry, you'll need to stiffen the follower.  A stiffer material or a thicker follower are options.

Comment: The vertical profile at each end of the profile would impart infinite acceleration to the follower. The design is wrong. Plot the motion profile, Y, as a function of horizontal position, X.

Comment: @Transistor, I think you've got the right idea. There are certain mechanical and physical constraints in systems such as this that have to be considered in the design. As the OP suggests that the only thing that can be changed is the follower, one might suggest a rotation to the follower (a windshield wiper-type movement) with appropriate mathematical modifications to the measurement results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the design to use a lobe - such as on a cam shaft with a follower.

Then you can get a high rate of change of vertical movement without the side loading you get from your design.

Comment: Unluckily I cannot change the cam shape or motion-

Comment: @marcotrevi you asked for a different design, I gave you one. Think about circles.

Comment: I can only change the follower/shaft design